# Strange looking garage beam support post

Tags: garage, beam, support

I was looking to buy this house and then realize this room is strange. It used to be a garage but got converted to living space (with permit):

[image]

It was a single lumber running across so I am not sure why it needs the support in the middle. I guess the span is too wide for that lumber.

Anyways, the support post looks weird:

[image]

Is this piece of metal a "Structural" component or just some "hack" from previous owner?

What do I do in order to remove this post? Larger beam?

Comment: It is a screw jack.

Comment: Loan is money I assume. Anyways, is screw jack a permanent support or temporary?

Comment: Looks like the remodel was interrupted. Additional walls were probably planned which would carry the load temporarily being supported by the triple 2x6 and screw jack

Comment: Also be concerned with the moldy sheetrock in lower portion of exterior walls  water is infiltrating them somehow.

Comment: I have no idea..lol It was the iPhone autocorrect thing.

Answer (score 2):

I would hire a structural engineer to give me a report on the existing conditions and include any needed support for that beam. Tell him your ideas and intentions so he can advise you what is needed or required.